# Get event of phone call receive and ending while vonage opentok video call is on going?

Tags: android, opentok, tokbox, phone-state-listener, videocall

I am working on vonage opentok video call functionality. I want to get an event of native phone call received and ending while video call is ongoing. please let me know if you found anything regarding that it will really helpful for me.

**Note**: I have already tried Broadcast receiver with READ_PHONE_STATE permission but it does not working in api leve 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new sample in the OT samples. It should be all you need - https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/tree/main/Phone-Call-Detection

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but when i was receive the phone call and end the call and then came back to video call then publisher view is getting black not able to see other users face. whenever session.onResume() is called. can you please help me regarding that.